# Searching multiple document on mongoose with the same ID in a array of ID

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have this little problem I'm using a NoSQL db with mongoose and I have two documents that contain a narray of ID

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5efa6e4aebbc0401a4f613a5"
    },
    "roomID": [
        "5efbb6d0531e4a5c0c08d06b"
    ],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-06-29T22:39:09.427Z"
    },
    "userID": {
        "$oid": "5efa6e49ebbc0401a4f613a4"
    },
    "__v": 0
} 

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5efb868fc569cb50c4505a63"
    },
    "roomID": [
        "5efbb6d0531e4a5c0c08d06b",
        "5efcf95183e3c6618c10db7a"
    ],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-06-30T18:36:43.851Z"
    },
    "userID": {
        "$oid": "5efb868fc569cb50c4505a62"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

and I want to search for each document that contain one **roomID** in specific like **5efbb6d0531e4a5c0c08d06b** which is in both documents

Answer (score 0):

const roomID = "5efbb6d0531e4a5c0c08d06b"
findMany({roomID:})

Answer (score 0):

Say your mongoose model is named `Chat`, then try below:

```
const rooms = await Chat.find({roomID: "5efbb6d0531e4a5c0c08d06b"})
```

Reference:
[MongoDB Manual - Query an Array for an Element](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element)